# A component which is hidden by another JSF/primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

hello,

I'am using JSF/primefaces 2.0
My problem is that I can't see the button "Add User" in the page,I think the problem is caused by the balise  **p:fileUpload**   because when I delete it I can see the button!!

```
 <table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="1000" heighth="1800">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h:form>

                      <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                         <tr> <td>  <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px" value="Nom" /> </td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.nom}" /></td></tr>
                         <tr><td>   <h:outputLabel value="Files"/></td><td><p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddPerson.fileUpload}"   update="messages"   sizeLimit="500000"    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/"/> </td></tr> 

                         <tr><td>  <h:commandButton action="#{AddPerson.addUserDB}"  value="Add User" /> </td></tr>  

                     </table>     
                 </h:form>             
             </td>
         </tr>
  </table>
```

The whole code:

```
<body>
        <table  border="1" style='width:auto;height:100px;' align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  >
            <tr><td>
                    <table  border="1" style='width:auto;height:100px;' align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr  >
                <td><h:graphicImage width="100" url="/ONST.jpg"/> </td>
                <td >                   
                    <h:graphicImage width="900" url="/banner_home.jpg"  />   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <br></br><br></br><br></br>
   <table border="1" align="center" style='width:auto;height:100px;' cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:form>

                        <table border="1" style='width:auto;height:100px;' align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" >


                            <tr> <td>  <h:outputLabel style="font-size: 13px" value="Nom" /> </td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.nom}" /></td></tr>
                            <tr> <td> <h:outputLabel value="Prenom"/></td><td> <h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.prenom}" /></td></tr>

                            <tr> <td>  <h:outputLabel value="Etat Civil"/></td>
                                <td> <h:selectOneMenu id="etatcivil" value="#{AddPerson.etatCivil}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Monsieur" itemLabel="M"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Madam" itemLabel="Mme"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Madmoiselle" itemLabel="Mlle"/>
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                                </td></tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><h:outputLabel value="Date de naissance "/>      </td>
                                <td>

                                      <h:selectOneMenu id="jour" value="#{AddPerson.jour}">
                                      <f:selectItem itemValue="00" itemLabel=""/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="01" itemLabel="01"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="02" itemLabel="02"/><f:selectItem itemValue="03" itemLabel="03"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="04" itemLabel="04"/><f:selectItem itemValue="05" itemLabel="05"/><f:selectItem itemValue="06" itemLabel="06"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="07" itemLabel="07"/><f:selectItem itemValue="08" itemLabel="08"/><f:selectItem itemValue="09" itemLabel="09"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="10"/><f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="11"/><f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="12"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="13" itemLabel="13"/><f:selectItem itemValue="14" itemLabel="14"/><f:selectItem itemValue="15" itemLabel="15"/>   
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="16" itemLabel="16"/><f:selectItem itemValue="17" itemLabel="17"/><f:selectItem itemValue="18" itemLabel="18"/>  
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="19" itemLabel="19"/><f:selectItem itemValue="20" itemLabel="20"/><f:selectItem itemValue="21" itemLabel="21"/>   
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="22" itemLabel="22"/><f:selectItem itemValue="23" itemLabel="23"/><f:selectItem itemValue="24" itemLabel="24"/>    
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="25" itemLabel="25"/><f:selectItem itemValue="26" itemLabel="26"/><f:selectItem itemValue="27" itemLabel="27"/>     
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="28" itemLabel="28"/><f:selectItem itemValue="29" itemLabel="29"/><f:selectItem itemValue="30" itemLabel="30"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="31" itemLabel="31"/>
                                         </h:selectOneMenu>


                                <h:selectOneMenu id="mois" value="#{AddPerson.mois}">
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="00" itemLabel=""/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="01" itemLabel="Janvier"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="02" itemLabel="Fevrier"/><f:selectItem itemValue="03" itemLabel="Mars"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="04" itemLabel="Avril"/><f:selectItem itemValue="05" itemLabel="May"/><f:selectItem itemValue="06" itemLabel="Juin"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="07" itemLabel="Juillet"/><f:selectItem itemValue="08" itemLabel="Aout"/><f:selectItem itemValue="09" itemLabel="Septembre"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="10" itemLabel="Octobre"/><f:selectItem itemValue="11" itemLabel="Novembre"/><f:selectItem itemValue="12" itemLabel="Decembre"/>
                                 </h:selectOneMenu>

                                 <h:selectOneMenu  id="annee" value="#{AddPerson.annee}" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1940" itemLabel="1940"/> <f:selectItem itemValue="1941" itemLabel="1941"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1942" itemLabel="1942"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1943" itemLabel="1943"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1944" itemLabel="1944"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1945" itemLabel="1945"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1946" itemLabel="1946"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1947" itemLabel="1947"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1948" itemLabel="1948"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1949" itemLabel="1949"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1950" itemLabel="1950"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1951" itemLabel="1951"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1952" itemLabel="1952"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1953" itemLabel="1953"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1954" itemLabel="1954"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1955" itemLabel="1955"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1956" itemLabel="1956"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1957" itemLabel="1957"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1958" itemLabel="1958"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1959" itemLabel="1959"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1960" itemLabel="1960"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1961" itemLabel="1961"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1962" itemLabel="1962"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1963" itemLabel="1963"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1964" itemLabel="1964"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1965" itemLabel="1965"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1966" itemLabel="1966"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1967" itemLabel="1967"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1968" itemLabel="1968"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1969" itemLabel="1969"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1970" itemLabel="1970"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1971" itemLabel="1971"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1972" itemLabel="1972"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1973" itemLabel="1973"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1974" itemLabel="1974"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1975" itemLabel="1975"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1976" itemLabel="1976"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1977" itemLabel="1977"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1978" itemLabel="1978"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1979" itemLabel="1979"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1980" itemLabel="1980"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1981" itemLabel="1981"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1982" itemLabel="1982"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1983" itemLabel="1983"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1984" itemLabel="1984"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1985" itemLabel="1985"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1986" itemLabel="1986"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1987" itemLabel="1987"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1988" itemLabel="1988"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1989" itemLabel="1989"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="1990" itemLabel="1990"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1991" itemLabel="1991"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1992" itemLabel="1992"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1993" itemLabel="1993"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1994" itemLabel="1994"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1995" itemLabel="1995"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1996" itemLabel="1996"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1997" itemLabel="1997"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1998" itemLabel="1998"/><f:selectItem itemValue="1999" itemLabel="1999"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2000" itemLabel="2000"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2001" itemLabel="2001"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2002" itemLabel="2002"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2003" itemLabel="2003"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2004" itemLabel="2004"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2005" itemLabel="2005"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2006" itemLabel="2006"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2007" itemLabel="2007"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2008" itemLabel="2008"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2009" itemLabel="2009"/>
                                    <f:selectItem itemValue="2010" itemLabel="2010"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2011" itemLabel="2011"/><f:selectItem itemValue="2012" itemLabel="2012"/> 
                                 </h:selectOneMenu>


                                </td>
                                </tr>

                            <tr><td><h:outputLabel value="email"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.email}" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>    <h:outputLabel value="numTelephone"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.numTelephone}" /></td></tr>
                            <tr> <td>  <h:outputLabel value="mobile"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.mobile}" /></td></tr>
                            <tr><td>   <h:outputLabel value="fax"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.fax}" /></td></tr>
                              <tr><td>  <h:outputLabel value="profession"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.profession}" /></td></tr>
                              <tr><td>  <h:outputLabel value="adresse"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.adresse}" /></td></tr>
                               <tr><td> <h:outputLabel value="code Postal"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.codePostal}" /></td></tr>
                               <tr><td> <h:outputLabel value="Ville"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.ville}" /></td></tr>
                               <tr><td> <h:outputLabel value="Pays"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.pays}" /></td></tr>


                               <tr><td> <h:outputLabel value="Domaine de Competence"/></td>
                                   <td>   <h:selectOneMenu  value="#{AddPerson.domain}" id="domaine" >
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select Domaine de Competence-- " itemValue="0"/> 
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{AddPerson.listDomaine}" />
                                       </h:selectOneMenu></td></tr>


                                 <tr><td><h:outputLabel value="login"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.login}" /></td></tr>
                              <tr><td>  <h:outputLabel value="password"/></td><td><h:inputText value="#{AddPerson.password}" /></td></tr>


                              <tr><td>   <h:outputLabel value="Files"/></td> <td> <h:panelGroup style="display:inline-block"> <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{AddPerson.fileUpload}"   update="messages"   sizeLimit="500000"    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" /></h:panelGroup></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>  </td><td>  <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Add User" action="#{AddPerson.addUserDB}"  /> </td></tr>  
                     </table> 

             </h:form>  

         </td>
     </tr>
  </table> 
    </td></tr></table>
 </body>
```

Comment: Have you tried playing with the table height? Like height="100%"   ? And anyway  INMO its a bad practice to set all your width an height in pixels...

Comment: yes I did,when I add component above <p:fileUpload> it's visible but below it's invisible

Comment: try wrapping the p:fileUpload with h:panelgroup with style="display:inline-block" or style="display:block" and set height of your table to 100%

Comment: @Daniel I have tried your suggestion but it didn't work!!

Comment: if you change the height:100px of the table to.... 200px ? Or another idea of mine would be , replace the <td>  </td> before the button with  <td><h:outputLabel value="My Button"/>  </td> , just guessing....

Comment: @ Daniel I have did that,I have change the height several times ,I have added outputlabel before the button!! I dont see the problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I cannot reproduce your problem.

This is how your given code looks in FF 11 (and similar in IE9 and Chrome 18):

[image: Firefox 11 Screenshot]

Maybe you have a stylesheet included somewhere else on your page that hides the button somehow..

Comment: the same problem always persist I will Update my question with the whole code(I just post a part)